# Defer rendering of web pages in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred-rendering

Wile I was reading [**This**](http://www.speedawarenessmonth.com/15-things-for-making-your-site-faster-for-mobile-users/) article I came to a point called `Defer Rendering`.

What I understood from this is that I can comment the part of the html page that is at first not visible to the user, and load it after 5 second using a `script`.

I have a page that loads a list of related adds from the database. I wanted to increase the speed of loading in the mobile.

So my question is : Can someone give me some working example on how I can go forward with it ?

Or are there other ways to do `Defer Rendering` ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a good recommendation.  While crawlers are pretty good at figuring what's on your page despite wonky HTML, by commenting out all of that markup, you risk hiding it from crawlers (and therefore search engines), as well as preventing the user agent from doing its just and any optimizations it may already have.  The browser is already built for showing pages to your users as fast as possible.  The only reason you would use this method would be to prevent a ton of redrawing later, but even then I wouldn't go this route.

Comment: If you want your page to load fast, consider limiting what you're loading.  Do you really need all of those ads visible?  There are many other things to consider first, before you get into the ugly hacks.

Comment: @Brad regarding the crawlers I am worried about it because its a mobile website of our current website . And the real website is already being indexed well by the crawlers . But yes I will look into the basic optimization well before I enter into the hack stuff.....

Comment: If you're splitting your mobile and regular site and think that this takes care of your crawler problem, then you likely already have a pretty bad SEO situation.  Google crawls your mobile pages as well.  How are you doing the split?  User-agent sniffing?  Do you set the `Vary:` header for this?  If you're relying on Google ignoring your mobile site, then what about all the folks that search on their phones and then land on your desktop site?